# Should writing logs to file be asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net

The documentation for .NET says:

> Logging should be so fast that it isn't worth the performance cost of asynchronous code.

However, I am accustomed to almost all I/O in C# being async.

This would include writing to a simple text file as part of my logging.
I work on a realtime graphics application which means, even if the overall execution time is longer by using async functions, this would be preferable to any blocking operation.

Is the overhead of opening, writing and saving a file (steps required to log to a file) not worth the performance cost of asynchronous code in C# / .NET?

Comment: Quite unclear how first ("logging *should be fast*") part of the post relates to the second ("IO is slow")... You may want to re-read first half of your post...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I didn't say I/O is slow but I am basically asking if writing a few lines to a file, as is done in logging, is fast enough that it can be done synchronously in a realtime application. I re-read the first half of my post and think this is clear, but suggestions on how I could make it more clear would be welcome.

Comment: Asynchronous code is like a playground where kids are active on many things at once. The opposite would be waiting for your gas to fill up at the gas station with others queued up behind you. I don't think there is one right or wrong. Async all the way is not a bad design philosophy and if that is what you are used to then queueing results based on a slow pump at the gas station probably wont make things horrible. Where I see people get in trouble is when they start to equate multi-threading to async programming. Spinning threads across 8 cores just to wait for IO operations can be wasteful

Answer (score 3):

The complete quote is:

> Logging should be so fast that it isn't worth the performance cost of asynchronous code. If a logging datastore is slow, don't write to it directly. Consider writing the log messages to a fast store initially, then moving them to the slow store later. For example, when logging to SQL Server, don't do so directly in a Log method, since the Log methods are synchronous. Instead, ***synchronously*** add log messages to an in-memory queue and have a background worker pull the messages out of the queue to do the ***asynchronous*** work of pushing data to SQL Server. [emphasis added]

[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line)

What they are describing *is* actually asynchronous logging, with respect to the final storage medium. It's just that the logger methods themselves are not async. The logger methods write to an intermediary store synchronously, then an asynchronous (background) operation writes it to the final location, which in your case would be the filesystem. This is completely consistent with what you're describing as asynchronous logging.